# How to create age-rang-filter form in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filters

I'm trying to design a form to allow user to filter data in run-time.
My model is:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city= models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField()
    birthdate= models.DateField()
```

Then, I created a Model form with two extra fields **ageFrom** and **ageTo** so that user can enter two values (age rang) and get data filtered using this age range.
This is my form

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #extra fields, which are not in my model, to filter by
    ageFrom = forms.IntegerField()
    ageTo = forms.IntegerField()
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        ageFrom = cleaned_data.get("ageFrom")
        ageTo = cleaned_data.get("ageTo")
        if ageFrom > ageTo:
            raise forms.ValidationError("some message ")
            
    class Meta:
        model = Case
        fields = ('country','city', 'gender')
        template_name = 'report/custom_report.html'
```

The problem is that the method **clean** doesn't work well. I don't get an error even the  `ageFrom > ageTo`.
Second I believe there is a better way to implement this filtering.
Could you please help me to find the best way to filter by ages rang. Or to get the method clean work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic should be opposite. `ageFrom` should be less than `ageTo`. Also, you need to return the cleaned data value from that method(that is the reason why you are getting error):

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    ageFrom = cleaned_data.get("ageFrom")
    ageTo = cleaned_data.get("ageTo")
    if ageFrom < ageTo:
        raise forms.ValidationError("some message ")
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ruddra for your reply. I've already added "return cleaned_data" but not working.

Comment: Are you calling `form.is_valid()` method somewhere in the view?

Comment: In my view i have something like that:
`form = ReportForm(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
        return render(request, "report/load_report_data.html",  context)
    else:
        return render(request, "report/report_error.html")`
I try to change values of ageFrom and ageTo but unfortunately, it always renders report/report_error.html"

Comment: Anyway, I did the validation in the view. and It works fine. Thank you very much for your help.